# Mongo db pulling part of the document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I've a document which has another nested document in it represent a changes (logging). Each change document has a timestamp, field, old and new values. Basically as you can see this document would grow a lot, and I really don't want to get all changes but only a recent one.

What I want to do is make a query and get **only those** changes which falls in between two time stamps. I am not interested in any other information in document, so I dont want to pull it, just recent changes.

```
    {
          .......
        "adwordsChanges":[
          {
             "timestamp":NumberLong("1400162491325"),
             "field":"syncState",
             "old":null,
             "new":"OK"
          },
          {
             "timestamp":NumberLong("1400162491325"),
             "field":"keywordId",
             "old":null,
             "new":NumberLong("23918779329")
          },
          {
             "timestamp":NumberLong("1400162491325"),
             "field":"adGroupId",
             "old":null,
             "new":NumberLong("16972286472")
          }
       ]
    }
```

This is what I've tried!

```
db.keywords.find(
{
    $and :[{"_id" : ObjectId("5374c7a7ac58b0d3b5e970fa")}, {"adwordsChanges.field" : "keywordId"}, {"adwordsChanges.timestamp" : {$gte:NumberLong("11111111"), $lte:NumberLong(99999999999999) }}]
})
```

Running Andrei's query I am getting compilation error:

```
assert: command failed: {
        "errmsg" : "exception: The top-level _id field is the only field currently supported for exclusion",
        "code" : 16406,
        "ok" : 0
} : aggregate failed
Error: command failed: {
        "errmsg" : "exception: The top-level _id field is the only field currently supported for exclusion",
        "code" : 16406,
        "ok" : 0
} : aggregate failed
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at doassert (src/mongo/shell/assert.js:11:14)
    at Function.assert.commandWorked (src/mongo/shell/assert.js:244:5)
    at DBCollection.aggregate (src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1149:12)
    at (shell):1:13
2014-05-27T15:23:54.945+0100 Error: command failed: {
        "errmsg" : "exception: The top-level _id field is the only field currently supported for exclusion",
        "code" : 16406,
        "ok" : 0
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use aggregation framework to filter subdocuments, like this:

```
db.keywords.aggregate({$unwind:"$adwordsChanges"},
                      {$match:{"adwordsChanges.timestamp" : 
                                      {$gte:1400162491325, $lte:23918779329},
                               "adwordsChanges.field" : "keywordId"}},
                      {$project:{_id:0,
                                 timestamp:"$adwordsChanges.timestamp",   
                                 field:"$adwordsChanges.field", 
                                 old:"$adwordsChanges.old",   
                                 new:"$adwordsChanges.new"   
                                 }});
```

**Explanation of difference between project and group**

Initially I thought original document should be returned and `group` was used to restore original document structure, i.e in this case `group`is opposite operation to `unwind`.  After clarification it became clear that only subdocuments were needed, then I replaced `group` operation with `project`, so that subdocuments were projected to root level.

Comment: Or you can also use $sort (by your timestamp) and $limit (how many you want) with this aggregation if you are only interested in recently changed records.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! It almost works, it gives me only `adwordsChanges` nested documents, but inside it is array of other objects. How do I get only which matches `keywordId` and be only in the time range?

Comment: Updated my answer. I added condition for 'field' and replaced last grouping with projection, so that now you have subdocuments on root level.

Comment: Andrei, Thanks a lot! Unfortunatelly I am getting compilation error!
I've updated my question with error

Comment: Sorry, removed adwordsChanges:0 line, try now

Comment: Great, that works! Could you please briefly update your answer with a description about difference in your answer using `group` and `project`. I am reading documentation but just want to make sure I am understanding it correctly.